# Technique used for generating the Google Protocol buffer classes from the .proto file?

Tags: compiler-construction, protocol-buffers, lexer

What lexer/parser does Google Protocol Buffer use for generating the Protocol buffer classes from the .proto file?

Or if not lexer/parser what is the brief high level algorithm used for doing this.

I would like to make my own custom template(proto) file independent from Protocol buffers file format specifications from which I can generate the classes.